# How to pass options objects as parameters to method set at second parameter of jQuery()?

Tags: jquery

At [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) :

**Important:** If the second argument is passed, the HTML string in the first argument must represent a simple element with no attributes. **As of jQuery 1.4**, any [event type](http://Important:%20If%20the%20second%20argument%20is%20passed,%20the%20HTML%20string%20in%20the%20first%20argument%20must%20represent%20a%20simple%20element%20with%20no%20attributes.%20As%20of%20jQuery%201.4,%20any%20event%20type%20can%20be%20passed%20in,%20and%20the%20following%20jQuery%20methods%20can%20be%20called:%20val,%20css,%20html,%20text,%20data,%20width,%20height,%20or%20offset.%20%20As%20of%20jQuery%201.8,%20any%20jQuery%20instance%20method%20(a%20method%20of%20jQuery.fn)%20can%20be%20used%20as%20a%20property%20of%20the%20object%20passed%20to%20the%20second%20parameter:) can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/), [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/), [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/), or [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

**As of jQuery 1.8**, *any* (emphasis added) jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter:

---

When passing `animate` as a property, the element appears to immediately set the `css` properties

```js
var div = $("<div></div>", {
     id: "foo",
     "class": "a",
     animate: {
        fontSize:"22px"
     },
     data: {
        fontSize: "12px"
     },
     text: "click",
     on: {
       "click": function(e) {
         $(this).css($(this).data())
       }
     }
   });

   $("body").append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Attempted to set the `duration` of `animate` two ways

```
  animate: {fontSize:"22px", duration:5000}
```

which does not appear to recognize the `duration` property , and

```
  animate: {fontSize:"22px", {duration:5000}}
```

which logs `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` error to `console` .

While setting `css:{transition: font-size 5s}` does return expected results

```js
var div = $("<div></div>", {
     id: "foo",
     "class": "a",
     animate: {
       fontSize:"22px"},
     data: {
       fontSize: "12px"
     },
     css:{
       transition: "font-size 5s"
     },
     text: "click",
     on: {
       "click": function(e) {
         $(this).css($(this).data())
       }
     }
   });

   $("body").append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

it should be possible to pass the `options` object to the `animate` method 
directly.

Question:

How to pass additional properties to `animate` , or other jQuery methods that accept multiple object properties as parameters; for example `duration` or  `step` to the `.animate()` method defined at second parameter to `jQuery()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default duration for the *animate* method is 400ms. And if you run the first snippet you posted, you'll see the CSS is animated for that short period (0.4s).

But a specific value for duration can only be passed via the second argument to *animate* in all available jQuery method signatures.

jQuery has no support for passing more than one argument to functions specified as properties in the plain object that is passed as second argument to *jQuery()*.

This can be seen from this code snippet taken from the [jQuery v1.12.0 sources](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js), near line 2912:

```
// HANDLE: $(html, props)
if ( rsingleTag.test( match[ 1 ] ) && jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
    for ( match in context ) {

        // Properties of context are called as methods if possible
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( this[ match ] ) ) {
            this[ match ]( context[ match ] );   // <-------------

        // ...and otherwise set as attributes
        } else {
            this.attr( match, context[ match ] );
        }
    }
}
```

So there is no way to pass a duration to *.animate* in that way, and so -- in the case of *.animate* -- the default duration of 400ms will apply.

#### Workaround 1: override default value

There is of course the option to change the default duration to the desired duration and restore it right after the `$(html, plainobject)` call:

```js
$.fx.speeds._default = 5000; // change default
var div = $("<div></div>", {
    animate: {
        fontSize:"100px",
    },
    text: "animated text",
});
$.fx.speeds._default = 400; // restore;

$("body").append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But then you can better chain the animate method:

#### Workaround 2: chain the *animate* call

```js
var div = $("<div></div>", {
    text: "animated text",
}).animate({
    fontSize:"100px",
}, 5000);

$("body").append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Workaround 3: create a plug-in

You could also define a plug-in that will accept an array of arguments for each method, instead of just one argument:

```
$.fn.multiargs = function(arg) {
    for (key in arg) {
        $.fn[key].apply(this, arg[key]);
    }
};
```

Now you can use the 2nd-arg-object to do it all, using arrays as values for the method-properties:

```js
$.fn.multiargs = function(arg) {
    for (var key in arg) {
        $.fn[key].apply(this, arg[key]);
    }
    return this;
};

var div = $("<div></div>", {
    multiargs: {
        text: ["animated text"],
        animate: [{
            fontSize:"100px",
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            done: function() {
                $(this).text('Done');
            }
        }]
    }
});

$("body").append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Workaround 4: patch jQuery library

If the jQuery code quoted at the start of my answer would be modified so that this line:

```
        this[ match ].apply(this, context[ match ]);
```

...was replaced by this:

```
        if ( jQuery.isArray( context[ match ] ) ) {
            this[ match ].apply(this, context[ match ]);
        } else {
            this[ match ]( context[ match ] );
        }
```

Then you could write this:

```
var div = $("<div></div>", {
    text: "animated text",
    animate: [{
        fontSize:"100px",
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        done: function() {
            $(this).text('Done');
        }
    }]
});
```

And you would get the same results as in workaround 3.

Note however that it might have undesired effects when a jQuery method really needs to get an array as the first argument. So this code would need some more tweaking to deal with such situations correctly.

Also note that if you would use a modified version of jQuery, you'll need to reapply that change whenever you want to upgrade to a newer jQuery version.

#### Workaround 5: Redefine $.fn.init at run-time

You could replace *$.fn.init* at run-time, and for all other functionality it provides you could rely on the original version of it:

```js
var prev_$_init = $.fn.init;
var init = jQuery.fn.init = function( selector, context, root ) {
    var match, elem,
        // redefine regexes that are private to jQuery:
        rquickExpr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/,
        rsingleTag = ( /^<([\w-]+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/ );

    // Handle HTML strings
    if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
        if ( selector[ 0 ] === "<" &&
            selector[ selector.length - 1 ] === ">" &&
            selector.length >= 3 ) {

            // Assume that strings that start and end with <> are HTML and skip the regex check
            match = [ null, selector, null ];

        } else {
            match = rquickExpr.exec( selector );
        }

        // Match html or make sure no context is specified for #id
        if ( match && ( match[ 1 ] || !context ) ) {

            // HANDLE: $(html) -> $(array)
            // Patch: do not treat jQuery object as context here:
            if ( match[ 1 ] && !(context instanceof jQuery)) {
                // Option to run scripts is true for back-compat
                // Intentionally let the error be thrown if parseHTML is not present
                // Patch: simplify this call, as context is not jQuery:
                jQuery.merge( this, jQuery.parseHTML(
                    match[ 1 ],
                    document,
                    true
                ) );

                // HANDLE: $(html, props)
                if ( rsingleTag.test( match[ 1 ] ) && jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
                    for ( match in context ) {

                        // Properties of context are called as methods if possible
                        if ( jQuery.isFunction( this[ match ] ) ) {
                            // Patch:
                            if ( jQuery.isArray( context[ match ] ) ) {
                                this[ match ].apply(this, context[ match ]);
                            } else {
                                this[ match ]( context[ match ] );
                            }

                        // ...and otherwise set as attributes
                        } else {
                            this.attr( match, context[ match ] );
                        }
                    }
                }

                return this;
            }
        }  
    }
    // Patch: forward call to original fn.init
    return prev_$_init.apply(this, arguments);
};
init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
    
var div = $("<div></div>", {
    text: "animated text",
    animate: [{
        fontSize:"100px",
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        done: function() {
            $(this).text('Done');
        }
    }]
});

$("body").append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works, but this copies quite some code from the original *$.fn.init* code and needs to redefine some private variables which the jQuery library defines outside of the *$.fn.init* method. I marked in comments with "Path" where I modified the original code.

It is clear that *$.fn.init* was not designed to be overruled like this.

Concluding, I feel the downsides of this approach are more important than the advantages it brings over workaround 3.

Comment: _"So there is no way to pass a duration to .animate in that way"_ Have been attempting to modify `$.fn.init` to use `Function.prototype.apply()` when an array, e.g.; an of objects, is passed at `context[match]` ; see `script.js` which is jQuery version 3.0, at lines `2924` - `2934` . Part of requirement of Question is to have ability to use `step` , `start` , `done` and other options available to `.animate()`

Comment: Of course if you alter *$.fn.init*, the sky is the limit, but then you are really editing the jQuery API. But with the 3rd workaround I offered you can pass *step, start, done* and other options. I have extended the last code example to include the use of *done*.

Comment: Tried that approach; did not return expected results as the value could be a string. Will post the version that did return expected results by modifying `$.fn.init` momentarily. Attempted to do so a few minutes ago, though stacksnippets crashed due to character limit

Comment: Strange, I tested the code I just posted, which deals with the text string as should be expected. What did you try that did not work?

Comment: Actually, attempt at using `$.isArray()` is first version at http://plnkr.co/edit/qKSOfy61ARQAPb5O5lc0?p=preview commented at `script.js` lines `2924` through `2934`

Comment: I added a workaround option 5, with snippet. It redefines *$.fn.init* at run-time, chaining it to the original one for other functionalities.