# Creating multiple html elements using an object and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

So I want to create a block of elements taking classes and attributes from an object.

I use a function to create the object

```
function profile(name, img, health, strength) {
    return {
        name: name,
        img: img
    }
};
```

Then I use jQuery to create a div and use the object to provide a class

```
function pushProfile(profile) {
    $('<div />', {
        "class": profile.name,
        "class": 'profile',
        text: 'test'
    }).appendTo('.profile-class');
};
```

So far it seems everything is working.
My question is can I add nested elements to the new div inside the same function? Something like this?

```
function pushProfile(profile) {
    $('<div />', {
        "class": profile.name,
        "class": 'profile',
        text: 'test'
    }).appendTo('.profile-class');
    $('.' + profile.name).prepend('<img src=' + '"' + profile.img + '" />');
};
```

I'm fairly sure what I wrote for adding the img is wrong but I can't seem to find any documentation on someone doing anything similar to this so I may just be going about this wrong. If anyone has any suggestions on a different method I am absolutely open to those.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or demo?

Comment: This should work. Once it's been added to the DOM you can just query it like you are doing now. Did you test it? Is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `prepend` as a property of `attributes` at `jQuery(html, attributes)`

```
function pushProfile(profile) {
    $('<div />', {
        "class": `${profile.name} profile`,
        text: 'test',
        prepend: `<img src="${profile.img}"/>`
    }).appendTo('.profile-class');
};
```

See also [How to pass options objects as parameters to method set at second parameter of jQuery()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526060/how-to-pass-options-objects-as-parameters-to-method-set-at-second-parameter-of-j)

Answer (score 0):

Set all your properties within the Object of your your element constructor function

```
function pushProfile(profile) {
    $('<div />', {
        "class": profile.name + ' profile',
        text: 'test',
        prepend: '<img src="' + profile.img + '">',
        appendTo: '.profile-class'
    });
}
```